# How to assign template to smarty admin folder

Tags: templates, smarty, assign

I have a smarty structure like this

```
/
/cache
/configs
/libs
/templates
/templates/administrator
/cache
/administrator
```

I want the same template structure assign to my  **administrator** folder. I am getting error :

> "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message 'Unable to load template file 'administrator/index.tpl"

The Code I am using is

```
$t = new smarty;
$t->setTemplateDir('.' . DS . 'templates/administrator' . DS)
        ->setCompileDir('.' . DS . 'templates_c' . DS)
        ->setPluginsDir(SMARTY_PLUGINS_DIR)
        ->setCacheDir('.' . DS . 'cache' . DS)
        ->setConfigDir('.' . DS . 'configs' . DS);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the template is actually `templates/administrator/index.tpl`, then it should be referenced as

```
$t->display('index.tpl');
```

since you have set `template_dir` to `templates/administrator`.  From the error, it appears you have attempted

```
$t->display('administrator/index.tpl');
```

If that is not the case, please update your question to show the `display()` call as well as the contents of `templates/administrator`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution:
I have created the template directory for the administrator